# display the result along with the unit

Tags: php, html

I have calculated average of the values in my php script.

```
<?php 
    $average=($sum/$num_rows);
    $_SESSION["average"]=($average);
?>
```

I want to display it in the html table along with its unit 'mg/l'. I don't know where should I add that so that it can be displayed together with the value.

```
<th>chloride</th>
<th><?= (!empty($_SESSION["average"])) ? $_SESSION["average"] : ""?></th>
```

So what should I do?
Thank you.

Comment: `<th><?= !empty($_SESSION["average"]) ? $_SESSION["average"] . 'mg/l' : ""?></th>`

Comment: Now the hard part. Which of all the answers will you accept? :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could just concatenate it:

```
<th>chloride</th>
<th><?= (!empty($_SESSION["average"])) ? $_SESSION["average"]." mg/l" : ""?></th>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just concatenate it to the session value.

This will add the two strings together, for example if the average was `5.4`, then it will append `mg/l` to the end to make `5.4mg/l`.

In PHP, the operator for concatenation is `.`.

For example:

```
<th><?= (!empty($_SESSION["average"])) ? $_SESSION["average"]."mg/l" : ""?></th>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can add it like this

```
<th><?= (!empty($_SESSION["average"])) ? $_SESSION["average"].'mg/l' : ""?></th>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use concatenation operator (`.`) to do this.

Try this:

```
<th><?= (!empty($_SESSION["average"])) ? $_SESSION["average"].' mg/l ' : ""?></th>
```